# Помогите найти ошибку в коде с авторизацией

Tags: php, авторизация

```
<?php
 require 'bd/db.php';
 session_start()

 ?>

 <?php

  $login = $_POST['login'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
     $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

  if($_SESSION['password']) {
   $count = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = 
  '$login' AND `password` = '$password'");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($count) == 0){
  echo "Вы не зарегестрированны";
 }
  else {
  echo "Все окей";
  }
} else {
  echo      "<form action='' method='POST'>
        <input name='login' placeholder='Введите логин'></br></br>
        <input name='password' placeholder='Введите пароль'></br>
        <button name='submit' type='submit'>Зарегестрироваться</button>
    </form>";
 }



?>
```

Должно быть так:Если пользователь есть в базе данных,то форма убирается,а если его нет,то выводит ошибку.У меня же получается,что в 2-ух случаях эта форма убирается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из вашего кода если существует пароль то убирать форму не зависимо от того есть пользователь или нет. Попробуйте не вводить пароль и у вас отобразится форма. Или же можно сделать так:

```
$form = "<form action='' method='POST'>
        <input name='login' placeholder='Введите логин'></br></br>
        <input name='password' placeholder='Введите пароль'></br>
        <button name='submit' type='submit'>Зарегестрироваться</button>
    </form>";

  $login = $_POST['login'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
     $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

  if($_SESSION['password']) {
   $count = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = 
  '$login' AND `password` = '$password'");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($count) == 0){
  echo "Вы не зарегестрированны";
  echo $form; //Показываем форму
 }
  else {
  echo "Все окей";
  }
} else {
  echo $form; //Показываем форму    
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо

```
 else {
  echo "Все окей";
  }
} else {
  echo      "<form action='' method='POST'>
        <input name='login' placeholder='Введите логин'></br></br>
        <input name='password' placeholder='Введите пароль'></br>
        <button name='submit' type='submit'>Зарегестрироваться</button>
    </form>";
 }
```

Попробуй это

```
    <?php
    if(empty($_SESSION['login'])) {
?>

<form action='' method='POST'>
        <input name='login' placeholder='Введите логин'></br></br>
        <input name='password' placeholder='Введите пароль'></br>
        <button name='submit' type='submit'>Зарегестрироваться</button>
    </form>

    <?php
}
else {
    ?>
```

Всё okey

```
    <?php   
}
?>
```